# My iPhone 5s is cracked and the screen is black, how do I get pictures from the phone?

Tags: iphone, unlock

I dropped my iPhone 5s in water and then cracked it... Vegas what can I say?

It was working that day but, the next it just went black and didn't work anymore. When I connected to the computer, it is  recognized  but it says is locked and obviously, I can't unlock it from the phone, is there a way to unlock it from my Mac?

How do I retrieve my pictures from an iPhone I can't unlock?

Comment: Did you have them backed up to iCloud, Google Photos, Dropbox, your computer, etc.? Was your phone backed up to iCloud or iTunes? Please comment below with `@JohnRamos` and I can further assist you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an iPhone data recovery software such as [iPhone Recovery](http://www.iphonerecovery.com/recover-data-from-broken-locked-iphone.html). Good Luck!